# Issue in update statement

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am writing the following lines of code to update the data in access database.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = String.Format(Queries.dbConnection, databasePath);
    con.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "update tblusers set password = @password where userId = @userId;";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", authResult.UserId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", newPassword);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

When this line runs `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` I got the following error:

> Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Am I missing anything?

**Update - 2**

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = String.Format(Queries.dbConnection, databasePath);
    con.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "update tblusers set password = ? where userId = ?;";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = newPassword;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = authResult.UserId;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: not directly related, but: actually storing the password in the database is a huge security problem for you and your users (people tend to reuse passwords, unfortunately); I *strongly* recommend switching to a cryptographic hash (with unique salt per user) model, storing just the hash (and salt, unless you use the userid to derive the salt, which can be valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: MS Access / OleDB does **not** used **named** parameters - but **positional** parameters. So the **order** in which you specify the parameters is very much relevant!

Second: OleDB uses the `?` as a parameter placeholder.

So try this code:

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "update tblusers set [password] = ? where userId = ?;";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    // parameters - do *NOT* use "AddWithValue", and specify in the *correct order*!
    // since the parameters are *positional*, the name provided is irrelevant
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = newPassword;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = authResult.UserId;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @Pankaj: sorry, yes, I missed the fact that `Password` is an Access SQL reserved keyword, so if you use it as your column name (rather bad idea), you **must put it** in square brackets in your SQL statement - updated my answer